# Nested z-index layering with unexpected results

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hr9etn07/5/)

**Description of problem:**

When clicking the `Click me` button, the `.list` element fades in on top of the `Menu` button, in spite of it having a lower z-index value.  I assume it has to do with inheritance, but I have explicitly specified a higher z-index value for the `.keep-on-top` element, so I'm confused by the behavior I'm seeing.

**Desired outcome:**

I would like for the `.list` element (i.e. the black box) to fade in beneath the menu button but above the blue `.header-color` div.  I welcome any solutions.

**Code:**

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-color"></div>
    <div class="keep-on-top"><button>Menu</button></div>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<button>Click me!</button>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.header-color {
    background-color: #0099cc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.keep-on-top {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 4;
}

.list {
    background-color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove z-index from class `header`